# How can I host an externally downloaded WMS layer on my GeoServer (i.e. without having to depend on the external source to stay online all the time)

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

I'm not a good language person so forgive me for skipping any details or not sounding clear, if you have not understood anything that I've said, please comment and let me know, I will do my best to explain it to you.

I'm trying to host an external WMS layer on my Geoserver, the issue starts when the WMS provider changes the layer name or URL which then disrupts my WMS Layer. I wanted to know there was any way on geoserver or REST/Python to download the WMS layer entirely, and then upload it on geoserver through my local machine so that it functions exactly like one but without having to depend on the online status of the external provider

I know you can do it for WFS layers (i.e. downloading as shapefile, GeoJSON etc and then hosting that file) and I know that WMS rasters can be downloaded in PNG or GeoTIFF, but those do not appear as tiles (i.e. on zooming, they lose quality instead of rendering new tiles like an actual WMS)

Comment: I think you already answered your own question in the last paragraph. You can't 'download a WMS'. If there is a WFS available with the same underlying data, you could download that, and create your own WMS based on that. Or contact the owner of the WMS and ask if data is available for download

Comment: Create a cached layer from the WMS source and seed it https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/layers.html. You can use the integrated GeoWebCache or a standalone. Ask from the service provider if they allow such usage. If they have limited resources it is also good to discuss when it is appropriate to generate load for their server due to seeding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MapProxy https://mapproxy.org/ between your App and the external WMS, and you can also configure your GeoServer/GeoWebCache in this manner (Thanks @ian-turton)

Set it to expire tiles only when you ask it to, and pre-seed it with everything.

This gives two disadvantages:

1. It may be forbidden to bulk download from the external WMS per their usage policy
2. Your cache is older than the raw source data.

I would really opt for a people-based solution: write to the people providing the external WMS and explain that you rely on their layer naming, and thus you would kindly ask them to keep the names stable.

Comment: That's really no different that using GeoServer/GeoWebCache to cascade the WMS

Comment: Can you set GeoServer to cascase, never expire and pre-seed all?

Comment: yes, of course - it will take a while and annoy the owner of the web site